# Raycast with Normal as the Ray Direction Doesn't work

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

I am trying to delete points along the Normals of instanced planes. The best idea I had was to Raycast but it won't take normal data as ray direction and I don't understand why.

Originally, I thought it was just not reading the data so I instanced the cones in the direction of the normal. They worked.
I did try a node setup of Sample Nearest Surface and that didn't work, same thing for a setup of Sample Index and Sample Nearest with Normals as the value.
[image: What I am currently getting]
[image: My node setup]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything manually. thx.

Comment: @Chris, Sorry about that I didn't think about that, I have attached it now

Comment: Wait, your sketch is confusing. You should describe what the GN (should) do. Actually, the targets are the planes behind the cones and you are shooting rays from every point of the grid in the direction of the face normals of the planes. Those points that hit a plane should be deleted.

Comment: ok, it's not a bug. Documentation reads: *Ray Direction: The field is evaluated on the geometry from the context of the field evaluation, not the Target Geometry."*. So the problem is the wrong target context. I've tested it with a field vector attribute on the source points and it worked. But this won't help you. According to your sketch you want to delete all points that the planes point to. But GN works the opposite way. The points shot at the planes & need a direction. If you could transfer the Normal of the target planes to every point then every point shots into 6 directions and [...]

Comment: [...] if the point hits *any* plane in *any* of the 6 directions if would get deleted.

Comment: @Blunder Is it possible for you to show me what you mean exactly? It sounds like its doable from what I am getting from your comment, because I am just trying to select these points along the Normals at the end of the day.

Comment: Reading your comment through again, I see that you are implying that it isn't possible given the current setup correct?

Comment: Yes, I think it's not possible. The problem is that you want to have *n* lasers shooting at *m* targets in *n* directions. But I think it's possible with a *Simulation Zone* or *Repeat Zone* (Blender 4.0) and let *n* lasers shooting at *m* targets in 1 direction. Then change the direction for each loop iteration. Or in other words, let the lasers shoot one after the other (technically points are lasers & the planes+cones are targets, visually it's vice versa). You must also check that the target you hit is really pointing in the direction of the shot, as you can hit several targets at once.